# Package update from JwtSecurityToken to .JsonWebToken is not working in Asp.net Code Minimal API

Tags: jwt

I have an ASP.Net Core 6 Razor minimal API project without controllers. I have implemented a custom authentication and authorization using JWT token.
Everything was working fine, until recently I was getting the nuget package update request for security vulnerability of [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken]. I completed the suggested NuGet package update to [Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken].

However, the solution is not working since then, It is generating JWT the token I validated the JWT token structure, it is a well formed JWT token, but when I am using that token in my request header to call my API, it say authentication failed.

It seems I need to replace JwtSecurityToken and corresponding JwtSecurityTokenHandler() to JsonWebToken and JsonWebTokenHandler()
But it seems I am going somewhere wrong, there is not enough documentation on this yet. I went through the following article but could not figure out how to implement it in my code. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events)
Here is the code I am using in my program.cs file.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateActor = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapPost(pattern: "/Api/V1.1/Identity/AuthorizationTokenByClientSecret",
    (ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModel ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModelObj, IAccessAuthorizationBusinessLogic service, HttpContext context) =>
    AuthorizationTokenByClientSecret(ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModelObj, service, context))
    .Accepts<ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModel>("application/json")
    .Produces<string>(contentType: "text/plain")
    .WithDisplayName("Identity");

IResult AuthorizationTokenByClientSecret(ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModel _ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModelObj, IAccessAuthorizationBusinessLogic _AccessAuthorizationBusinessLogicObject, HttpContext _httpContext)
{
    try
    {
        var _result = _AccessAuthorizationBusinessLogicObject.GetTokenByClientSecret(_IdentityConnectionStringIdName, _ApiAuthorizationTokenRequestModelObj, _remoteIpAddressAspPerAPIService);
        if (_result != null)
        {
            var _claims = new List<Claim>();
            _claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, _result.Result.AccountName));
            _claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, _result.Result.AccountDisplayName));
            _claims.Add(new Claim("ClientApplicationCode", _result.Result.ClientApplicationCode));
            _claims.Add(new Claim("ClientOrganizationCode", _result.Result.ClientOrganizationCode));
            foreach (string _rolename in _result.Result.ClaimRoleNames)
            {
                _claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _rolename));
            }
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken
            (
                issuer: builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims: _claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
            string tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return Results.Ok(tokenString);
        }
        else
        {
            return Results.BadRequest("Authorization Token un-successful!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Results.Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```